# Attempted to call function "curl_init"

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, curl, zend-framework

I know this question was answered a lot of times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=call%20to%20undefined%20function%20curl_init) but I tried many things and I cannot fix it.

I am developing using symfony 3.

First of all I thought I hadn't php-curl so, I decided to install it doing

> sudo apt-get install php-curl

It worked! So, I restarted Apache... and tried again.. and the error jumped again. I saw too I should  *"delete"* the **; of a php.ini line** but... surprise! There is not any line with:

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

I thought then maybe I didn't really install php-curl... so I did:

> var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));

And the answer is:

> Current PHP version: 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

EDIT: I followed [this](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/PPA-migration-to-ppa:ondrej-php):

And now appears

> Current PHP version: 5.6.26-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1

Then I tried to:

> sudo apt-get install php5-curl

And is happens:

> tureey@tureey:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package php5-curl

Actually these are my software stats:

- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Release: 16.04
- Codename:    xenial

And after do:

> php -v

PHP 5.6.23-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)

Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

I did and upgrade and update but nothing changes... any solution?

Comment: Did you try to `sudo apt-get update` before installing the package?

Comment: `var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));` will output a boolean. It's not going to give you "Current PHP version:xxx" as you said. I'm also unsure why you're trying to use an old version of PHP with 16.04. 16.04 comes with PHP 7.

Comment: Yeah... I fixed it this morning unistalling all the LAMP and installing again... I don't know why it happened

Answer (score 0):

Correct package should be php5.6-curl